# Slow SFTP Speeds with Raspberry Pi on Local Network

Tags: networking, nautilus, 15.04, sftp, raspberrypi

I am using my Ubuntu Desktop (15.04) to connect to my Raspberry Pi 2 on my local network. To access the files, I would like to mount the RPi using Nautilus's "Connect to server" feature. When I use this, it works great for a few minutes. After about 10 minutes or so, it begins to slow down dramatically. I am saving simple python scripts, maybe 10k, so the transfer should be nearly instantaneous, yet it sometimes takes a minute or two to save.

Here's what I've figured out:

- When I reboot the RPI, I have the same problem, but when I reboot Ubuntu, everything is fixed.
- I once tried to log into the RPi after Ubuntu had been running for about an hour, and I still had this problem.
- Internet speeds are fine when it is stalled trying to save.

I'm not a networking expert, but the first two items tell me it is not a problem with my RPi and the last one tells me it is not a problem with my network. That said, it is my conclusion that it is a problem with Ubuntu. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

**Note:** I have also tried mounting it from the command line using `sshfs`. I had the same issue.

**Update:** When I run `sudo ping -f [RPi ip]` for 30 minutes, this is the output. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ydrzpzgv57h0oe/output?dl=0)

Comment: Try running 'sudo ping -f [raspberry_pi_ip_address]' and give the output after you've left it running for 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

which soft are you using?
for example,ftp or just LAN shared files?
When typing IP address on Nautilus, Nautilus have to decide which software to use.
so assume your RPI IP is 192.168.1.2, if your RPI were using ftp ,then type : ftp://192.168.1.2. (sftp maybe the same, I haven't used)
if you are using LAN shared files, make sure the directory of RPI has been shared with all the permissions. Then try type IP on Nautilus again.

Comment: I am using `sftp://pi@192.168.1.151/home/pi`. I am using a sftp connection, and am having no problems connecting. It just slows down drastically within a few minutes.

Comment: Try type cmd in terminal. Is the speed slows down drastically,too? I feel like it's the nautilus's problem itself.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you mean type `sftp://pi@192.168.1.151/home/pi`? Because that does nothing.

Comment: The GUI shell(Nautilus) is calling the other module or function to implement this sftp. The problem can be itself or the module. If the command in terminal can upload quickly , then the problem can locate on the GUI shell, otherwise the problem can locate the calling module.

Comment: No, I means the command of sftp. Tpye: sftp root@192.168.1.151. Then type put localfile_path remotefile_path. These two path is your file's path.

Comment: As I said in my original post, I have tried mounting the remote drive using sshfs and continued to have the same problem.

Comment: All right , I just thought it's the Nautilus's problem. Only using command lines in terminal can make sure the problem should blames Nautilus or not. Forgive my poor English.